# Dual monitor setup with Display port and vga

Tags: display, vga, displayport

I have a motherboard that has a Display port and a VGA output. I would to use 2 screens. But my question is if it would work using both ports.

Kind regards,

SaltyPotato

Comment: It depends on the motherboard. With some you will simply get the same display on  both screens. With others you will get what I assume you want,   extending your desktop onto the second screen. If you list the motherboard make and precise model it may be possible to find the info for you.

Comment: What your motherboard/processor is is essential here.

Comment: Is this a lenovo machine?

Comment: On second thought, please just run "sudo lshw -short" or windows equivalent in terminal and append the output to your question. Thanks

Comment: What's happened to this 3-year-old question? It showed up on the first page of Superuser. Nevertheless, I would give my suggestion: if you're running an Intel CPU, check its ARK page (example: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75036/intel-core-i5-4430-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-20-ghz.html); there's a '# of Displays Supported' field, and go ahead if it shows at least 2 (which is usually the case).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could run two screens if you have one monitor plugged into displayport and one into VGA. However, there is a possibility that the motherboard would not be able to handle it, but nearly all modern ones should. If you have a graphics card though I would recommend plugging your monitors into that if possible or at least one monitor to the card one to the motherboard.

Comment: Sadly I got a graphics card but it is to big for my motherboard. Heatsink is in the way. Thanks for the reply nonetheless going to try it soon!

Answer (score -3):

Yes, this will work. You will then need to set the  monitors up. The steps in doing this vary depending on the motherboard brand. A quick google with motherboard brand can point you in the right direction.